# Javascript checkbox two math operation did not display the right value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i operate 2 math operation inside jquery ?

```
result = val;
a = result * 5000;
b = result * 0.1;
result = a + b;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ugdjezb/ 
my codes didn't give the right result

```js
function calculate() {
  var j = document.getElementById("output");
  var rege = /^[0-9]*$/;
  var price = $('#price').val();
  if (rege.test(price)) {
    val = parseInt(price);
    var result = val;
    if ($('input[name="selectedItems1"]').is(":checked")) {
      a = (result * 5000);
      b = result * 0.1;
      result = a + b;
    } else {
      result = result * 5000;
    }
    if (isNaN(result))
      j.value = 0
    else
      j.value = result;
  } else
    alert("Error in input");
}
$(function() {
  $('input[name="selectedItems1"]').change(function() {
    calculate();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Price" id="price" onkeyup="calculate()" />
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems1" value="val1" />Tax 10%
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="output" value="Output" />
</form>
```

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: And I thought [**this**](http://needsmorejquery.com/) was a joke!

Comment: I don't see a sign of jQuery in your code. Except for the load listener!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir `$('input[name="selectedItems1"]').is(":checked")` there is not enough jQuery - using the DOM AND jQuery is confusing. He should use one or the other

Comment: the result i was expecting if price = 1 without tax,the result is 5000.but added more 10% tax,total will changed into 5500 ( 5000 + 500),but the result there is 5000.1 @guest271314

Comment: Use `b = a * 0.1` https://jsfiddle.net/7ugdjezb/1/. Also event handler attribute function should be defined before attribute at `html`.

Comment: the result is still same @guest271314

Comment: @BaktiWijaya _"the result is still same"_ ? Not here. Input `1`, `5500` should be result at jsfiddle.

Comment: that one works too on JS Fiddle @guest271314

Comment: what about inserting another checkbox ? @guest271314

Comment: _"what about inserting another checkbox ?"_ Not sure what you mean? Original Question is resolved, yes?

Comment: yeah,i'm just trying to make another checkbox,thanks anyway @guest271314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a cleaned up version. Please note the

`result += (result * 0.1);` part

```js
function calculate() {
  var $outPut = $("#output"),
    rege = /^[0-9]*$/,
    price = $('#price').val() || 0,
    result = 0;
  if (!rege.test(price)) {
    console.log("Error in input");
  } else {
    result = parseInt(price) * 5000;
    if ($('input[name="selectedItems1"]').is(":checked")) {
      result += (result * 0.1);
    }
  }
  $outPut.val(result.toFixed(2));
}
$(function() {
  $('#price').on("keyup",calculate);
  $('input[name="selectedItems1"]').on("change",calculate);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Price" id="price" />
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems1" value="val1" />Tax 10%
  <br/>
  <input type="text" id="output" value="Output" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is good in jsfiddle, its just you are doing wrong calculation in it. I'm assuming you want to find 10% of number you write in textfield.

If yes, the here you're doing it wrong

```
result = a + b;
```

Just replace above line with this in your fiddle and it'll work.

```
result = b;
```

Comment: i already tried but it only returns with the result of b,not result + b.i was expecting a = result * 5000 ,b = result * 0.1,so a + b = 5500 @myke_11j

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
a = (result * 5000);
b = result * 0.1;
result = a + b;
```

should be:

```
a = (result * 5000);
b = a * 0.1; // calculate 10% of (result * 5000) not result
result = a + b;
```

or in one line like this:

```
result *= (5000 * 1.1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using bodmas, brackets over division over multiplication over addition over subtraction.

```
results = (result * 5000) + result * 0.1;
```

Comment: i already did,i tried result = (result * 5000) + (result * 0.1); but the result still the same @Web Dev Guy

Comment: Ahh kk thought you was asking how to perform 2 maths operations.